# Room Error in one of the sequential processes

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

i have left join structure in my room database. Just for simplicity I am giving the code below:

#### Parent

```
@Entity(indices = [Index(value = ["name"], unique = true)])
data class Artists(
    val name: String,
) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int = 0
}
```

#### Child

```
@Entity(foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(entity = Artists::class,
    parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
    childColumns = arrayOf("artistsId"),
    onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
    onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
)
data class albums(
    val title: String,
    val artistsId: Int
) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int = 0
}
```

#### Viewmodel

```
viewModelScope.launch {
id = insertArtists(Artists("1"))
insertAlbum(Albums("title1", id))
}
```

If there was an error in inserting the insertAlbum, how can I revert inserting the insertArtisits. what i meant is that I want to remove the data added with Artists("1"). What is the best way to achieve this or i ll use the below code?

```
//if there is a error in insertAlbum()
deleteArtists(id)
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Transaction